# throw new applicationexception c# but in debug mode do not highlight it

Tags: c#-4.0, exception, visual-studio-2012

Hi it is possible throw new applicationexception c# but in debug mode do not highlight it in window for particular applicationexception for VS 2012.

no need to show error window

i had tryed it but i do no get solutions.

[image: no need to show error window]

Answer (score 1):

You can attribute your method with the `[DebuggerStepThrough]` attribute.

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public static void ThrowError(...)
```

---

Alternate way you can try: In Visual Studio, go to the "Debug" menu and select "Exceptions". In the following dialog you can choose on which exceptions Visual Studio should stop.

Please note that this is a global setting for the project. It won't stop on any `ApplicationException` then, not just on the one that was thrown in `ThrowError`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. but when calling ThrowError(...) Method it is high lighting in there now. it is possible that should not high light that when it calls that method?

Comment: See my edit. This might help you. Also, you need to handle it somewhere, don't forget!